# How do I turn off the "Convert Extension Method to Plain Static" automatic refactoring in resharper?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, extension-methods

When using Resharper, for some reason, when I call an extension method, it automatically converts it into a static method call.  This is the so called [Convert Extension Method to Plain Static](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Convert_Extension_Method_to_Plain_Static.html?permalink) refactoring.

```
foo.Bar()
```

becomes

```
MyStaticExtensions.Bar(foo);
```

Ironically, it then flags this as a code smell. How do I turn this off?

Comment: Is there a fix already?

Comment: Worst feature of Resharper ever

Comment: just saw this happen today in R# 9.1
changed     
    myvar.Select(Mapper.Map<Bar, Foo>).ToList()
to     
   Enumerable.ToList(myvar.Select(Mapper.Map<Bar,Foo>))

Comment: A 6 year old bug is back!

Comment: I'm having this problem in R# 9 as well.

Comment: For reference here is a link to a related bug on the JetBrains YouTrack:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-433571

Answer (score 4):

This feature is embedded in the IntelliSense of Resharper. I'm using Linq-to-sql extensions a lot, so I have disabled this feature: Resharper - Options - IntelliSense - Enable Radiobutton Visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't happen for me (Resharper 4.5).  Do you have "silent clean up" enabled? (Resharper - options - Code Cleanup).

Comment: Nope, it doesn't look like I have any cleanup profiles set up.  This actually only happens in a particular circumstance. Namely a Linq To SQL extension method defined in a partial class.

Comment: @Charles:  ok, that makes more sense (that its a particular circumstance).  I'll try to repro...

Comment: Does anyone have the fix for this yet? It's really annoying as it converts it from an extension method to a static method call (when using auto clean up) and then suggests I convert it back again! :) LOL

Answer (score 1):

You can disable this behavior by unchecking `Optimize 'using' directives`. It's a pity R# has such insane behavior; even more strangely only for a few files. I'd guess it only happens if a static method on `Enumerable` is called in the current file.

In order to obtain the using sorting and cleaning behavior, I recommend installing Productivity Power Tools and checking `Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> Organize Usings -> Place 'System' directives first when sorting usings.`